# Spring boot Hikari connection pool issue

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

In my spring boot 2.3 application, i am connecting to Oracle DB however I am having a connection issue every 10 mins or so. I am not sure why the total is always 1

Here is my connection details

```
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource    
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000    
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=50    
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000    
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=15000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=DeGPool
```

Here are my debug logs

```
2021-01-04 23:48:11.756 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 leakDetectionThreshold..........15000
2021-01-04 23:48:11.756 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 maxLifetime.....................2000000
2021-01-04 23:48:11.756 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 maximumPoolSize.................20
2021-01-04 23:48:11.757 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 metricRegistry..................none
2021-01-04 23:48:11.757 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 metricsTrackerFactory...........none
2021-01-04 23:48:11.757 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 minimumIdle.....................20
2021-01-04 23:48:11.757 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 password........................<masked>
2021-01-04 23:48:11.757 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 poolName........................"DeGPool"
2021-01-04 23:48:11.758 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 readOnly........................false
2021-01-04 23:48:11.759 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 registerMbeans..................false
2021-01-04 23:48:11.760 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 scheduledExecutor...............none
2021-01-04 23:48:11.760 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 schema..........................none
2021-01-04 23:48:11.760 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 threadFactory...................internal
2021-01-04 23:48:11.760 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 transactionIsolation............default
2021-01-04 23:48:11.760 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 username........................"api"
2021-01-04 23:48:11.761 [main      ] DEBUG   c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1098 validationTimeout...............5000
2021-01-04 23:48:11.761 [main      ] INFO     c.z.hikari.HikariDataSource:110  DeGPool - Starting...
2021-01-04 23:48:12.175 [main      ] DEBUG     c.z.hikari.pool.HikariPool:564  DeGPool - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@27cf3151
2021-01-04 23:48:12.177 [main      ] INFO     c.z.hikari.HikariDataSource:123  DeGPool - Start completed.
2021-01-04 23:48:12.279 [ousekeeper] DEBUG     c.z.hikari.pool.HikariPool:421  DeGPool - Pool stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
```

Comment: Did you tried without minimumIdle? did you have leak warnings?

Comment: You don't post the rest of the log. HikariCP should continue adding connections after startup, up to the minimumIdle level. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Yes, i have the latest version. Yes I removed minimumIdle but no leak warnings observed.